# Service is not implemented

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, grpc

I have this contract in a common library that is used by the server and the client:

```
namespace GestorOrdenadores.Service.Comun
{
    #region Contracts (Interfaces)
    //El contracto que tendrá que ser implementado por el servicio y llamado y utilizado por el cliente.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IGreeterService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(HelloRequest request, CallContext context = default);
    }
    #endregion Contracts (Interfaces)




    #region Messages
    [DataContract]
    public class HelloReply
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class HelloRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion Messages
}
```

I have this service in a ASP NET Core project, and implements the interface:

```
namespace GestorOrdenadores.Server.Grpc.DotNet.Services
{
    public class GreeterService : IGreeterService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        #region implementación del servicio
        public Task<Service.Comun.HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(Service.Comun.HelloRequest request, CallContext context = default)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                   new Service.Comun.HelloReply
                   {
                       Message = $"Hello {request.Name}"
                   });
        }
        #endregion implementación del servicio
    }
}
```

And I have a librarry for the client gRPC, that will be use for another applications, WPF application, console application, Xamarin... The code is this:

```
namespace GestorOrdenadores.Cliente
{
    public class ClienteGrpcDotNet
    {
        #region constructores
        public ClienteGrpcDotNet()
        {
            //var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5206");
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5206");
            //var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:5001");
            _client = channel.CreateGrpcService<IGreeterService>();
        }
        #endregion constructores



        private IGreeterService _client;



        public async Task<string> SayHelloAsync()
        {
            HelloReply miRespuesta = await _client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });

            return miRespuesta.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when in my client I call the service, I get this error: Service 'GestorOrdenadores.Service.Comun.GreeterService' is unimplemented.

This message is shown in the console application that runs the service.

I have tried to delete de method in the service that implements the interface and then with wizard of Visual Studio, I solve the problem creating the method. But it still tells that the service is not implemented.

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Grpc doesn't use the ServiceContract and OperationContract annotations.  It uses code generated from the .proto file (which is the contract).  See some of the basic examples for grpc-dotnet on how a service is implemented and registered with a server. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/a04684ab2306e5a17bad26d3da69636b326cce14/examples/Greeter/Server/Startup.cs#L44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Grpc... this is a bit special than others.

We use Interface to separate the contract from the actual implementation behind for normal code.

But for gprc, `.proto` file is a contract itself. Therefore, there was no need for an interface here, the lib would generate the class for us instead (one way another, accross many other languages).

That's why on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/aspnet/core/grpc/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), they create a class that inherit from some out-of-nowhere class got generate by the lib when we build the project.

And classes got inherited from them are compatible with `channel.CreateGrpcService<SomeService>`. Of course, DI register would be vary among all those kind of projects (web server, WPF, console,...). So... just read through the doc, they actually right.